# Get lowest value from array and remove duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to:
 1. get lowest value [alert] for [id_vehicle]
 2. remove duplicates of [id_vehicles]
 3. sort array by [id_vehicle]

So in this case lowest value is 2016-03-07. How can I do this? This is my array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [id_vehicle] => 35
                [remind] => 2016-03-07
                [alert] => 2016-10-09
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 3
                [id_vehicle] => 35
                [remind] => 2016-05-02
                [alert] => 2016-03-07
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 4
                [id_vehicle] => 35
                [remind] => 2016-08-01
                [alert] => 2016-05-02
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 5
                [id_vehicle] => 35
                [remind] => 2016-11-07
                [alert] => 2016-08-01
            )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: I don't have idea how to do this. I think i need some foreach function or usort?